# Retrieving URIs in Report of OWL2DL violations in the OWL API

Tags: owl, owl-api

I need to check the violations to the OWL2DL profile in this simplified ontology:

```
@prefix : <http://www.onto.com/test#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.onto.com/test#> .

<http://www.onto.com/test#> rdf:type owl:Ontology ;
                             rdfs:label "Test"@en .

xsd:date rdf:type rdfs:Datatype .

<http://www.onto.com/test#hasPart2> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .

<http://www.onto.com/test#isPartOf> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
                                             owl:TransitiveProperty ;
                                    rdfs:domain <http://www.onto.com/test#TestRestriction> .

<http://www.onto.com/test#isPartOf2> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                                     rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topObjectProperty ;
                                     rdf:type owl:TransitiveProperty ;
                                     rdfs:domain <http://www.onto.com/test#A2PartOfClass> .

<http://www.onto.com/test#maxCardinality0> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .

<http://www.onto.com/test#A2PartOfClass> rdf:type owl:Class .

<http://www.onto.com/test#TestRestriction> rdf:type owl:Class ;
                                           rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                             owl:onProperty <http://www.onto.com/test#isPartOf2> ;
                                                             owl:minQualifiedCardinality "0"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                                                             owl:onClass <http://www.onto.com/test#A2PartOfClass>
                                                           ] ;
                                           rdfs:comment "A1 PartOf Class Comment"@en ;
                                           rdfs:label "A1PartOfClass"@en .


<http://www.onto.com/test#isPartOf2> rdf:type owl:Class .
```

To this end, I have the following code in the OWL API to check for the violations of the given ontology to the OWL2DL profile.

```
OWL2DLProfile profile = new OWL2DLProfile();
OWLProfileReport report = profile.checkOntology(ontology);
for(OWLProfileViolation v:report.getViolations()) {
   System.out.println(v);
}
```

In the console I'm getting this:

```
Use of non-simple property in a restriction: ObjectMinCardinality(0 <http://www.onto.com/test#isPartOf2> <http://www.onto.com/test#A2PartOfClass>) [SubClassOf(<http://www.onto.com/test#TestRestriction> ObjectMinCardinality(0 <http://www.onto.com/test#isPartOf2> <http://www.onto.com/test#A2PartOfClass>)) in OntologyID(OntologyIRI(<http://www.onto.com/test#>) VersionIRI(<null>))]
```

And I would like to retrieve the URIs involved, i.e.,  http://www.onto.com/test#isPartOf2, http://www.onto.com/test#A2PartOfClass
as well as the message of the violation, i.e., Use of non-simple property in a restriction.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the signature of the axiom involved in the violation as follows:

```
violation.getAxiom()
  .signature()
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

There is no easy way to get the type of the violation besides doing the following:

```
violation.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

which will return `UseOfNonSimplePropertyInCardinalityRestriction`.

Comment: `OWLProfileViolationVisitor` can be used to run code specific to each violation type.

Comment: This is what I need. I'm using OWL API version 4.5. Can you point me to a specific example regarding the implementation of `OWLProfileViolationVisitor`?